# suppress job object information display in powershell

Tags: powershell

When you start a job via the start-job command, when the job starts it displays job object information, for example the below:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
129    xtot            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            param ($piByteTotalsec...
131    xcbw            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            param ($piCurrentBandw...
133    xptsec          BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            param ($piPacketssec) ...
```

Is there a way to keep that from showing up, to suppress the display of that job object information yet still get what ever the ps code was suppose to return as its product?

Comment: How are you in a position where asking this makes sense? Either you're keeping this information somewhere so you can use it with `Receive-Job` and you aren't seeing it, or you're not using this information because you're using `Get-Job | Receive-Job` and you're not puzzled by whether you can still get whatever the PS code was supposed to return because you already know you can. Anyway, supress that from the pipeline with any of the normal methods, `$null = start-job ..` or `start-job .. | out-null` or `[void](start-job ..)` or just assign it to a variable you don't use `$whatever = start-job`

Comment: what position? You mean the position where i'm relatively new to powershell and its the first time i've used jobs (start-job) and did not know? Thanks for your reply, helped :)